# align text into the center of top and bottom?

Tags: align

how to align the paragraph or text to top and bottom in the right side of the image.

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\includegraphics[width=10mm,scale=0.1]{universe}
\LARGE\color{orange}{There's a picture of a galaxy above}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------


\end{document}
```

My result

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Specifying both `width` and `scale` options for `\includegraphics` can't be a good idea. You may want to specify `width` and `height` options.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `adjustbox`, that can add options to `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=10mm,valign=c]{example-image}
There's a picture of a galaxy here.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use `\LARGE` font size, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

{\LARGE \includegraphics[width=10mm,valign=c]{example-image}
There's a picture of a galaxy here.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This might not seem “vertically centered”, but such concept is not really well defined because characters may have depth. If I add rules above and below, the centering will clearly appear.

[image]

Comment: Trying to large the font but it's not aligned to the center

\parbox{10mm}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
\LARGE{There's a picture of a galaxy above}

Comment: @UDOT Do I suggest `\parbox` in my answer? By the way, `\LARGE` doesn't take an argument.

Comment: @UDOT I added the correct code for `\LARGE`.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

Thanks to [mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\parbox{10mm}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
There's a picture of a galaxy above
\end{document}
```

## Old

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\parbox[c]{10mm}{\includegraphics[width=10mm]{example-image}}
There's a picture of a galaxy above
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I'd be tempted to replace `[width=10mm]` with `[width=\linewidth]`, though, so that the width of the image is always the same as that of the surrounding `\parbox`. Also, the `[c]` vertical positioning specifier is the default and hence needn't be provided.

Comment: @Mico Thank you. I have update.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is to understand the basic concepts.

Each element in LaTeX has a boundary box (BB) with following features: width, height, depth and baseline (have a look at [LaTeX/Boxes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes)). LaTeX by default aligns elements with respect to their baselines. Usually, baselines lie at the bottom edge or close to the bottom edge of a BB; this is why you get a "bottom" alignment by default (see the image 1).

LaTeX provide a command to manipulate boxes: [`\raisebox{}[][]{}`](https://latexref.xyz/_005craisebox.html), e.g. the image 2 was lowered using the following command

```
\raisebox{-8pt}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}
```

The first argument is a distance by which a box is risen/lowered. The optional arguments specify new features height and depth of a BB of an element; you could have a large image and reduce its BB to a single line.

The main point behind `adjustbox` is we don't really need to do the any calculation manipulate BB because the packages already does so. Since you have added `adjustbox` with `[export]`, you have access to extra options, mainly `valign`; the value `c` does exactly what you request (See the image 3)

```
\includegraphics[width=1cm,valign=c]{example-image}
```

If you require another alignment, e.g. the top or the bottom, simply change `c` to `valign=t` or `valign=b`, respectively (See images 4 and 5). There is an additional value `m` for the middle alignment. The difference is `c` centres elements (here an image) w.r.t a strut, that is between the lowest point `-0.3\baselineskip` and the topmost point `0.7/baselineskip`, whereas the `m` takes the middle vertical point of an image and places it w.r.t. a baseline of a previous box.

Please note, there are additional values `T`, `M` and `B` which do the same as `t`, `m` and `b` but suppress any adjustments provided by `adjustbox`. The latter is controlled by `\adjboxvtop`, `\adjboxvcenter`, and `\adjboxvbottom`. The adjustments for boxes 7 and 8 is changed to achieve top alignment w.r.t capital `X` (image 7) and a bottom alignment w.r.t. a letter `y` (image 8)

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\begin{document}
1) Xxy \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image},
2) Xxy \raisebox{-8pt}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}

\bigskip

3) Xxy \includegraphics[width=1cm,valign=c]{example-image},
4) Xxy \includegraphics[width=1cm,valign=t]{example-image},
5) Xxy \includegraphics[width=1cm,valign=b]{example-image}

\bigskip

\renewcommand\adjboxvtop{1.6ex}%
% \renewcommand\adjboxvcenter{0.5ex}%
\renewcommand\adjboxvbottom{-2pt}%
6) Xxy \includegraphics[width=1cm,valign=c]{example-image},
7) Xxy \includegraphics[width=1cm,valign=t]{example-image},
8) Xxy \includegraphics[width=1cm,valign=b]{example-image}
\end{document}
```